# Combinatorics: Assigning People to Rooms

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume there are $2k$ students being assigned $2$ to each of $k$ rooms.  What is the probability of two given students ending up in the same room?

This seems to be a straightforward combinatorial problem but I can't find the solution. I'm trying to find the total number of assignments first and to then find the number of assignments in which the two students are in the same room.

Comment: Hint: you can use symmetry to simplify the probability computation. Regardless of which room person $A$ goes to, there are $2k-1$ equally likely other spots for person $B$ to go into. How many of those put $B$ into the same room as $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 
$$
B=\frac{(2k)!}{2^k}
$$
equally likely assignments of students to rooms without any restrictions. If we impose the restriction that two given students end up in the same room we are left with
$$
A=\frac{k(2k-2)!}{2^{k-1}}
$$
assignments (choose which of the $k$ rooms to put the two given students in and then assign the remaining $2k-2$ students to the remaining $k-1$ rooms. Forming the quotient, the probability is
$$
\frac{A}{B}=\frac{1}{2k-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For the total number, put the students in a line. Permute them all and then divide in groups of $n/k$ each. Take out the order of each group by dividing over $(n/k)!$ Probably you will see that there are $\frac{n!}{(n/k)!^k}$ ways to do this.
 For the ways in which your known students are in the same room, pick the room in which they are going to be in $k$ ways. Choose the other students in the room in $\binom{n-2}{(n/k)-2}$ ways and place the $n-(n/k)$ remaining students in the other $k-1$ rooms.

**Edit:** Apparently the question change and now $n=2k.$ Same idea works.